# Click on image not working with puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to get some historical stock data from here:
https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm

I am using puppeteer and this is what I have tried:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm');
    await page.click('#symbol');
    await page.keyboard.type('SONACOMS');
    let getData = '#get';
    await page.waitForSelector(getData);
    await page.click(getData);
    await page.waitForSelector('#historicalData');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'nse.png'});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

The input gets filled correctly , but the click does not seem to
be working. The code hangs forever.

To debug I tried following from the developer console:

```
document.querySelector('#symbol').value = 'SONACOMS';
document.querySelector('#get').click()
```

This works correctly. So I am not sure what I am missing in the puppeteer code.

Answer (score 0):

The site is pretty wonky and I'm not sure what's causing the hang, but should be scrapable by bypassing the DOM and hitting the search URL directly:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(
    "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm",
    {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}
  );
  const symbol = "SONACOMS";
  const searchUrl = `https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=${symbol}&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=day&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE`;
  await page.evaluate(`
    fetch("${searchUrl}")
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(html => document.body.innerHTML = html)
  `);
  const data = await page.$eval("table", el =>
    [...el.querySelectorAll("tr")].map(e =>
      [...e.querySelectorAll("th, td")].map(e =>
        e.textContent.trim()
      )
    )
  );
  console.table(data);
  const table = await page.$("table");
  await table.screenshot({path: "nse.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```